# Dasein Cloud API

Tags: api, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud

Is anybody using this API? I am trying to connect to Amazon S3 and EC2, following [this paper here](http://ignum.dl.sourceforge.net/project/dasein-cloud/Dasein%20Cloud%20Overview.pdf), but I get stuck on that line:

```
    CloudProvider provider = Class.forName(args[0]).newInstance();
```

Don't know what to put inside forName function or how to implement or get CloudProvider instance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this:

```
(CloudProvider) Class.forName("org.dasein.cloud.aws.AWSCloud").newInstance();
```

Comment: can you help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505525/how-to-connect-with-azure-cloud-blob-storage-using-dasein-api ?